# Reactive form is not marked Invalid even thought its controls are marked as invalid, why?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Having a form 'myForm' and one of its children being called 'myChildren'.
When the 'myChildren' control becomes invalid:

**Expected behavior**: when any of the children is invalid, the parent should be marked as invalid too.

```
myForm.invalid // true
myForm.controls.myChildren.invalid // true
```

**Actual behavior:**
the 'myChildren' status is not bubbling up to its parents and the form is marked as VALID even though one of its control is marked INVALID

```
myForm.invalid // false
myForm.controls.myChildren.invalid // true
```

Why does it work differently?
How do I keep the status in sync (If any of the children control or grand children control is marked as invalid, the whole form should be marked as invalid)

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. The code matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the way children controls were created.

```
 // this works as expected (form im marked invalid when myControl becomes invalid
 this.form.addControl('myControl', this.fb.control(undefined)) 

 // this does not work as expected (validation does not bubble up)
 this.form.controls = {myControl: this.fb.control(undefined) }
```